# how does the DomainDataSource.SubmitChanges know the methods to call on the server

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I configure the DomainDataSource to execute a particular server side method by setting the Query property.  If I then make changes to the retrieved data, and call SubmitChanges the control somehow knows the correct method to call. (UpdateEmployee for example)  Where is the name of the update method set, or it is simply inferred by some sort of naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inferred through a naming convention along with signature. An UpdateXXX/ModifyXXX method taking in a Employee as parameter is the update method for employees.

Alternatively, if the name of the method doesn't match the convention, then you can configure it via an attribute [Update] on the method. The signature still has to match.

Hope that helps.